# How to find/highlight HTML tags in a large block of text that aren't one of a list of allowed tags?

Tags: html, parsing

I have a large dataset containing lots of rich-text edited content blobs which are being migrated to another system.  The new system is stricter than the old when it comes to allowed HTML tags and we need to be able to identify what tags in the data would be cut or encoded and included in the content in a bad way on entry, before we migrate the data.

So for example given this HTML:

```
<h1>My page</h1><p>Lorem ipsum<marquee>SURPRISE!</marquee></p>
```

We wouldn't be interested in the "h1" and "p" tags (which are listed in an exception list somewhere,) but ideally we'd want to be able to see the "marquee" tag highlighted so in a visual spot check the bad tags can be easily identified and manually dealt with (right now we don't anticipate there being many bad tags in the dataset.)

It's easy to strip unwanted tags (thinking simple PHP/Python/whatever) - but we don't want to do that and potentially lose data.

Equally it's easy to encode tags, but we don't want to import ugly useless tags as part of the content.

What's the best way of doing this kind of thing?  I can't help but think there's a simple solution I'm missing or that I'm thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: it you are manually editing the content, and you simply want to highlight the problem tags, why not simply use javascript? on the client side?

Comment: I agree. Why not just use CSS? If some elements are invisible you could do something like `marquee:before, marquee:after {content: "!!!"; color: yellow}` instead of styling the actual element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS may be your friend in this case

```
   * {
     text-decoration: line-through;
    }
   h1, p <list other allowed tags> {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the surprise tags have printable representations (e.g. `<a href='#anchor'></a>`)

Comment: You could always give it a width/height/background-color/whatever. If you are doing manual removal, this seems like a pretty simple solution to me.

Comment: That could be solved by using `:before` or `:after`. But why would anyone have an empty `a` like that? Or did you mean the old myth `<a name="anchor"></a>`

Comment: Aha!  Yep, this is the elegant answer that was out of reach from my mind.  I think that should cover the majority of cases, and then any surprisingly represented allowed tags we can look at individually/ignore as necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could concievably use XPath to get a list of surprise elements:

```
//*[name() != 'h1'
    and name() != 'p'
    and name() != 'b'
    and name() != 'span'
    and name() != 'div'
    and name() != 'body'
    and name() != 'a']
```

in your language of choice or something like [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en) (Chrome).

The answer to "[XPath 1.0 to find if an element's value is in a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025885/xpath-1-0-to-find-if-an-elements-value-is-in-a-list-of-values)" might give an easier to read answer.

Comment: I like this approach too, just as elegant - but I can hand the CSS solution off to a business guy to play with themselves ;)  Thanks though, appreciate it - I feel bad because this is my first question and I can't upvote yet!