# C# Removing entire elements from XMLDocument based on list of unwanted attribute values

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

I have an XML file, e.g.

```
<Bars1>
    <Bar name='0'>245</Bar>
    <Bar name='1'>180</Bar>
    <Bar name='2'>120</Bar>
    <Bar name='3'>60</Bar>
    <Bar name='4'>0</Bar>
</Bars1>
<Bars2>
    <Bar name='0'>25</Bar>
    <Bar name='1'>10</Bar>
    <Bar name='2'>10</Bar>
    <Bar name='3'>6</Bar>
    <Bar name='4'>0</Bar>
</Bars2>
<Gubbins3>
    <Bar name='0'>45</Bar>
    <Bar name='1'>18</Bar>
    <Bar name='2'>12</Bar>
    <Bar name='3'>4</Bar>
    <Bar name='4'>0</Bar>
</Gubbins3>
```

and a `List<int>` notNeededBarNames, containing e.g.  { 1, 3 }

I have loaded the XML file into an `XmlDocument` xmlDoc, and want to remove ANY "Bar" element where the attribute "name" is one of the integers from my list, regardless of where it might exist in the XML .  My example is small, but in reality the document and the list could be quite large.

Is there a nice elegant approach to doing this?  I can "brute force" it, but I can't help feeling there might be a better way.

Hope you can help!

Comment: `I can "brute force" it` First do it, than ask a specific problem about your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq2Xml can make the life easier.

```
var notNeededBarNames = new List<int>() { 1, 3 };
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

xDoc.Descendants("Bar")
    .Where(bar => notNeededBarNames.Contains( (int)bar.Attribute("name")) )
    .Remove();

var newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

For an xpath-based solution, you can select the nodes to remove as follows:

```
private static void TestXmlBars()
    {
            string s = @"<root>
                                        <Bars1>...</Bars1>
                                        <Bars2>...</Bars2>
                                        <Gubbins3>...</Gubbins3>
                                    </root>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(s);

            List<int> exclude = new List<int>{1,2};
            // create comma-delimited list
            string list = "," + String.Join(",", exclude) + ","; 
            string xpath = String.Format("/root/*/Bar[contains('{0}', concat(',', @name, ','))]", list);
            XmlNodeList nodesToExclude = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodesToExclude)
            {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
    }
```

(Note that xpath 1 is constrained as it has no 'in' functionality, hence the 'contains' workaround - see [XPath 1.0 to find if an element's value is in a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025885/xpath-1-0-to-find-if-an-elements-value-is-in-a-list-of-values))

Comment: What is `ToStringElements` ?

Comment: See the bottom of my post (not sure why it stayed on the previous line - I will edit it to be more visible)

Comment: Why do you not use `String.Join` ? What does `ToStringElements` better?

Comment: Just used to using it I guess :) However, your suggestion is better, so I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var notNeededBarNames = new[] {1, 3};
        var elems = new[] {"Bars1", "Bars2", "Gubbins3"};
        var newXDoc = new XElement("root");
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load("PathToYourXmlFile");
        foreach (var elem in elems)
        {
            newXDoc.Add(new XElement(elem));
            var curElem = newXDoc.Elements(elem).Single();
            string xpath = String.Format("root/{0}/Bar", elem);
            var childElems = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
            foreach (var childElem in childElems)
            {
                bool add = true;
                var nameAtt = childElem.Attribute("name");
                if (nameAtt != null)
                {
                    int val = Convert.ToInt32(nameAtt.Value);
                    if (notNeededBarNames.Any(x => x == val))
                    {
                        add = false;
                    }
                }
                if (add)
                {
                    curElem.Add(childElem);   
                }
            }
        }
        var newXml = newXDoc.ToString();
    }
}
```