# sql xquery to add xml block into specific position

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, xquery, sqlxml

Using sql server 2012 sp1 I haven't been able to find a solution out there but I believe that its not possible to add xml block into specific position of an existing xml column in a table.  For example say we had `tbTable.AnimalsXML` which is:

```
<Animals>
  <Animal name="Dog">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
  <Animal name="Cat">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
  <Animal name="Bird">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
  <Animal name="Sheep">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
</Animals>
```

How does one insert:

```
<Animal name="Goat">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
</Animal>
```

in between Cat and Bird blocks?

Tried [position()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191225.aspx) and found this [problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/383888/fully-support-position-in-xquery), how do we get it done in sql using:

```
update tbTable set AnimalsXML.modify('
            insert
                sql:variable("@var")
            as "specific position"
            into (/Animals)[1]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`insert ... after ...`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx) construct to insert new element after certain existing element. Example below inserts new element after the existing `<Animal name="Cat">` element :

```
declare @data XML = '<Animals>
  <Animal name="Dog">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
  <Animal name="Cat">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
  <Animal name="Bird">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
  <Animal name="Sheep">
    <Enclosure id="Default">
      <Value>xyz</Value>
    </Enclosure>
  </Animal>
</Animals>'

set @data.modify('
insert 
    <Animal name="Goat">
        <Enclosure id="Default">
          <Value>xyz</Value>
        </Enclosure>
    </Animal>
after (/Animals/Animal[@name="Cat"])[1]
')
```

Comment: awww thanks, I was using first & last and getting nowhere, but didn't know about before & after as per [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175466.aspx