# Matching an array/list of values in xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking to match a list/array of values in my xpath expression and would like to know if that's possible.

**My XML**

```
<Parent-tag>
        <Child-Tag>
            <status>Up</status>
            <prop-name>prop-1</prop-name>
        </Child-Tag>
        <Child-Tag>
            <status>Up</status>
            <prop-name>prop-2</prop-name>
        </Child-Tag>
        <Child-Tag>
            <status>Down</status>
            <prop-name>prop-3</prop-name>
        </Child-Tag>
        <Child-Tag>
            <status>Up</status>
            <prop-name>prop-4</prop-name>
        </Child-Tag>
</Parent-Tag>
```

**I would like an XPATH like below**

```
/Parent-Tag/Child-Tag[prop-name=('prop-1', 'prop-2','prop-3')]/status
```

I tried two xpath testers online:

(1) https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#xpath-examples

(2) https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html

In (1), the above expression returned values, but in (2) it returned with a syntax error.

I am not sure if this is something to do with XPATH versions. Would you know if the latest XPATH supports this? If yes, is there an alternative to doing this in older XPATH versions?

This said, I understand this can be achieved like this (***but not something I would like***):

```
/Parent-Tag/Child-Tag[prop-name='prop-1' or prop-name='prop-2' or prop-name='prop-3')]/status
```

Comment: It's definitely because of versions. The first site fully supports XPath 2.0 / 3.0 specification. The second - probably only 1.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath 1.0 to find if an element's value is in a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025885/xpath-1-0-to-find-if-an-elements-value-is-in-a-list-of-values)

Comment: Your xml also is not well-formed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `contains` as shown below. (Tested in chrome browser to make sure the xpath works in Xpath 1.0 as browser support xpath 1.0 only)

```
/Parent-Tag/Child-Tag[contains('prop-1, prop-2, prop-3',prop-name)]/status
```

**Evidence Browser Version:**

[image]

**Evidence XML Version:**

[image]