# How to filter data from xml content using xpath queries to create a temporary table

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath, xquery

I am trying to create a sql query using xpath where i am looking to filter the data i need and put that in a temporary table.
Example:

```
  <superStarsDoc>
        <names>
            <starname>
                <preferredname>pref</preferredname>
                <firstNm>Bradd</firstNm>
                <lastNm>Pitt</lastNm>
            </starname>
        </names>
    </superStarsDoc>

and i am trying to get something like this but not working



with data(firstName,lastName) as 
(
unnest(xpath('/superStarsDoc/names/starname/firstNm[@firstNm="Bradd"]/text()',
(select xmlparse(document superstar_doc))))::text as firstName
,unnest(xpath('/superStarsDoc/names/starname/lastNm[@lastNm="Pitt"]lastNm="/text()',
(select xmlparse(document superstar_doc))))::text as lastName
from dbname.superstartable
)
```

I tried searching for solution but i did not find anything specific for my requirement, i dont have any attribute to point to that record exactly.

I tried using the following solution but that is not working, i am getting syntax error.
[XPath 1.0 to find if an element's value is in a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025885/xpath-1-0-to-find-if-an-elements-value-is-in-a-list-of-values)

Note: I typed the code here as i cannot copy paste my code exactly, so please excuse any typos

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: i used postgres data base

Answer (score 0):

You should probably fix your XPath with :

```
/superStarsDoc/names/starname/firstNm[.="Bradd"]/text()
/superStarsDoc/names/starname/lastNm[.="Pitt"]/text()
```

Generic code :

```
with superstartable(superstar_doc) as ( 
values (
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <superStarsDoc>
        <names>
            <starname>
                <preferredname>pref</preferredname>
                <firstNm>Bradd</firstNm>
                <lastNm>Pitt</lastNm>
            </starname>
        </names>
    </superStarsDoc>
'::xml)
)

SELECT
    xpath('/superStarsDoc/names/starname/firstNm[.="Bradd"]/text()', superstar_doc)[1] as "first-name",
    xpath('/superStarsDoc/names/starname/lastNm[.="Pitt"]/text()', superstar_doc)[1] as "last-name"
from superstartable
```

Comment: I am getting the following error

ERROR:  function xpath(unknown, character varying) does not exist
LINE 7:     (xpath('/superStarsDoc/names/starname/firstNm[.="B...
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: What's the output if you remove the leading (before xpath) and closing parenthesis ?

Comment: Actually this worked for me
Select unnest(xpath('/superStarsDoc/names/starname[firstname ="Bradd"]/firstname/text()'
(select xmlparse(superstar_doc_field_in_table))))::text as firstName