# Slow SQL query to get values from xml where some value is in xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to make my SQL execution faster.

I have the table with a XML column. XML stored is in this format:

```
<r eid="bdcd3ba2-e370-4140-8c46-01aed584bab2">
    <name>
        <customValue>Aperol</customValue>
    </name>
    <description></description>
    <num>46310660710877889975</num>
    <outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>ccbdd540-3bb4-4a9f-a8d3-5a31b9459846</outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>
    <type>DISH</type>
</r>
```

I want to get `<outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>` value from XML row, where `<type>` in XML is DISH and `<num>` is in ('46310660710877889975', '46310660710877889976', '46310660710877889975', '46310660710877889975')

My SQL queries:

this takes 1 minute and 44 seconds

```
SELECT
    m.c.value('(name/customValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS dish
FROM 
    _fabbrica.dbo.entity dish
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT CAST(dish.xml AS xml) AS realxml) s
CROSS APPLY
    s.realxml.nodes('r') m(c)
WHERE
    dish.type = 'Product' 
    AND m.c.value('(type/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'DISH' 
    AND m.c.value('(num/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') IN ('94948475659909879621', 'code', 'code')
```

This query takes 2 minutes

```
SELECT 
    dish.id, 
    SUBSTRING(dish.xml, (CHARINDEX('<customValue>', dish.xml) + 13), (CHARINDEX('</customValue>', dish.xml) - CHARINDEX('<customValue>', dish.xml) - 13)) AS 'Dish', 
    SUBSTRING(outerEanCode.xml, (CHARINDEX('<outerEanCode>', outerEanCode.xml) + 14), (CHARINDEX('</outerEanCode>', outerEanCode.xml) - CHARINDEX('<outerEanCode>', outerEanCode.xml) - 14)) AS 'OuterEanCode'
FROM 
    [_fabbrica].[dbo].[entity] dish 
JOIN 
    [_fabbrica].[dbo].[entity] outerEanCode ON outerEanCode.id = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( '<outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>', dish.xml ) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING( dish.xml, ( CHARINDEX( '<outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>', dish.xml ) + 39 ), ( CHARINDEX( '</outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>', dish.xml ) - CHARINDEX( '<outerEconomicActivityNomenclatureCode>', dish.xml ) - 39 ) ) ELSE '61D63FE7-212C-4847-BA32-1563D97E2424' END
WHERE 
    dish.type = 'Product' 
    AND SUBSTRING(dish.xml, (CHARINDEX('<num>', dish.xml) + 5), (CHARINDEX('</num>', dish.xml) - CHARINDEX('<num>', dish.xml) - 5)) IN ('94948475659909879621')
```

Are there some ways to change or create another query to reduce the execution time?

Comment: How many rows in `_fabbrica.dbo.entity`? And how many with `type = 'Product'`? Also does each XML just have a single `<r>` element as in the example or multiple?

Comment: But in any event query changes will only get you so far, you would likely to need to create an XML index on the table or an indexed computed column that exposes the XML values that you need to filter on

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you for the reply!
In _fabbrica.dbo.entity I have 67 171 rows,
25 946 rows are with type = 'Product'.
Each XML just have a single <r> element.

Comment: Hmm. unless the XML is very big then 1 minute and 44 seconds does sound exceptionally slow to process that number of rows then. Can you paste the actual execution plan here? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @MartinSmith
I added two execution plans for my two queries.
1) [execution plan for the first SQL where XML type used](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1_Eye0Fi)
2) [execution plan for the second SQL where string type used](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SysOggRFs)
Thank you for the service for sharing execution plans!

Comment: Does look like the `IN` list is optimized badly here. It doesn't just find the value and check if it is in the list it adds a ton of operators to the plan that take about 1:28

Comment: And for your string one looks like you have the problem that `Expr1008` in the compute scalar isn't just evaluated once but ends up getting repeatedly re-evaluated in the same way as I had here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30862/optimising-plans-with-xml-readers

Comment: @MartinSmith could you please give me some advice on how to optimize IN list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `m.c.value('(num/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') in (...)` list seems to be optimised badly ([execution plan link from comments](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1_Eye0Fi)) with each element in the list adding a sub tree to the plan. The concatenation operator at the top of all these is showing an elapsed time of 1min 28 seconds.

[image]

One way to avoid this would be to just evaluate `m.c.value('(num/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')` once per document and materializing the result to a temp table or table variable and then querying *that* with an `IN`.

But [the below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967753/73226) seems to solve the issue without that

```
SELECT m.c.value('(name/customValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as dish
FROM _fabbrica.dbo.entity dish
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(dish.xml as xml) as realxml) s
CROSS APPLY s.realxml.nodes('r[type = "DISH"][num =(
    "46310660710877889975","94948475659909879621","94948475659909879704","94948474748856478602",
    "46310660710877881223","94948475659909879363","94948474748847478248","26310360710077875944",
    "94948475659909879207","94948475659909879700","94948475659909879650","94948474748856478612",
    "94948474748856478618","94948475659909879704","94948474748856478496","46310660710877896883",
    "46310660710877881223","94948475659909879363","94948474747747475446","94948475659909879366",
    "94948475659909879121","26310360710077875994","94948475659909877377","94948475659909879123",
    "94948475659909879124","94948475659909879122","94948474748847478246","94948475659909879549",
    "94948474748856478594","94948474748847478244","94948475659909879597","94948475659909879363",
    "94948474747747475446","94948475659909879366","94948475659909879121",
    "94948475659909879123","94948475659909879122","46310660710877890446"
)]') m(c)
WHERE dish.type = 'Product'
```

You say in the comments that this has improved things and post [the below execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy75ObRYj). This still looks very slow to me. The elapsed time is 12.162 seconds even though the index seek to select the data was only  0.024 seconds. This still means that 99.8% of the execution time was taken up with parsing XML.

[image]

It looks to me that the actual casting of the string to XML [is deferred](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30947/3690)  and that this casting is being repeated every time the expression `Expr1002` is referenced in the plan (by the red highlighted operators). In particular the CPU time spent by the filter which does nothing except have a start-up predicate on `[Expr1002] IS NOT NULL` makes me think that.

If you are unable to change the source column to use XML datatype then you can do

```
SELECT CAST(xml AS xml) as realxml 
INTO #Product 
from _fabbrica.dbo.entity where type = 'Product'
```

And then change the query to operate against that temp table without any casting needed.

Comment: Great solution!
Thank you very much.
Now execution takes only 11 seconds. I'm happy :)
[execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy75ObRYj)

Comment: @Myrkytyn - If you are able to change the original column datatype to XML you should see quite an improvement on that. I think `[Expr1002]` is being repeatedly re-evaluated for the same document in multiple points in that plan (the casting of the string to XML)

Comment: Or you could go back to materialising to a temp table if not possible and do `SELECT CAST(xml AS xml) as realxml INTO #Product from _fabbrica.dbo.entity where type = 'Product' ` then query that temp table without any cast. I would expect that it ought to be possible to get this to run in well under 1 second given that the actual index seek from `entity` only takes 0.024 seconds in your latest plan

Comment: It might be possible to prevent the individual xpath filtering of each IN() value with a values table value constructor: `AND m.c.value('(num/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') IN 
(select v.v from (values('46310660710877889975'),('94948475659909879621')...) as v(v))`

Comment: @MartinSmith I cannot change the column to XML datatype, because another production app uses this database.
I made changes to create a temp database and now it takes only 3 seconds to get a query result. Thank you!